# Wait for element to appear when using Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I wonder if there's a similar way as in Selenium to wait for text to appear for a particular element. I've tried something like this, but it doesn't seem to wait:

```
await page.waitForSelector('.count', {visible: true});
```

Comment: For reference, there's an open issue when using `{visible: true}` with a non-specific selector - i.e. one that might match multiple elements: it only checks visibility of the first matched element: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/4356

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `waitForFunction`. See https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforfunctionpagefunction-options-args

Including @elena's solution for completeness of the answer:

```
await page.waitForFunction('document.querySelector(".count").inner‌​Text.length == 7');
```

Comment: I've used `await page.waitForFunction('document.querySelector(".count").innerText.length == 7');`

Comment: What about waiting to see text anywhere in the screen?

Comment: You can use `page.waitFor` and pass a function that looks up the text content from DOM. [Docs here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectororfunctionortimeout-options-args)

Comment: Although it's use-case dependent, I find I almost always `.trim()` my `.textContent` on `waitForFunction` callbacks to make sure a space-only element doesn't pass the predicate.

Answer (score 17):

Apart from the method presented in the answer from nilobarp, there are two more ways to do this:

#### page.waitForSelector

Using the pseudo selector [`:empty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty) it is possible to find elements that contain no child nodes or text. Combining this with the [`:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) selector, we can use [`page.waitForSelector`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectorselector-options) to query for a selector which is not empty:

```js
await page.waitForSelector('.count:not(:empty)');
```

---

#### XPath expression

If you not only want to make sure that the element is not empty, but also want to check for the text it contains, you can use an XPath expression using [`page.waitForXPath`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforxpathxpath-options):

```js
await page.waitForXPath("//*[@class='count' and contains(., 'Expected text')]");
```

This line will only resolve after there is an element on the page which has the attribute `class="count"` and contains the text `Expected text`.

Answer (score 8):

The best solution you can do using `waitForFunction()` (avoid weird function as  string):

```
const selector = '.count';
await page.waitForFunction(
    selector => document.querySelector(selector).value.length > 0,
    {},
    selector
);
```

Depends of the type of the text, replace `value` by `innerText`.

Check [puppeteer API](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.19.0/docs/api.md#pagewaitforfunctionpagefunction-options-args)

Answer (score 1):

### page.waitFor()

You can also just simply use [`page.waitFor()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectororfunctionortimeout-options-args) to pass a function **or** CSS selector for which to wait.

**Wait for Function**

If the element is an [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) field, we can check that the `.count` element exists before checking that a [`value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#htmlattrdefvalue) is present to avoid potential errors:

```
await page.waitFor(() => {
  const count = document.querySelector('.count');
  return count && count.value.length;
});
```

If the element is **not** an [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) field, we can check that the `.count` element exists before checking that [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) is present to avoid potential errors:

```
await page.waitFor(() => {
  const count = document.querySelector('.count');
  return count && count.innerText.length;
});
```

**Wait for CSS Selector**

If the element is an [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) field that contains a [`placeholder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#htmlattrdefplaceholder), and you want to check if a [`value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#htmlattrdefvalue) currently exists, you can use `:not(:placeholder-shown)`:

```
await page.waitFor('.count:not(:placeholder-shown)');
```

If the element is an [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) field that does **not** contain a [`placeholder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#htmlattrdefplaceholder), and you want to check if the [`value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#htmlattrdefvalue) attribute contains a string, you can use `:not([value=""])`:

```
await page.waitFor('.count:not([value=""])');
```

If the element is **not** an [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) field that does not have any child element nodes, we can use `:not(:empty)` to wait for the element to contain text:

```
await page.waitFor('.count:not(:empty)');
```

---

### page.waitForXPath()

**Wait for XPath**

Otherwise, you can use [`page.waitForXPath()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforxpathxpath-options) to wait for an XPath expression to locate element(s) on the page.

The following XPath expressions will work even if there are additional classes present on the element other than `count`. In other words, it will work like `.count`, rather than `[class="count"]`.

If the element is an [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) field, you can use the following expression to wait for the [`value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#htmlattrdefvalue) attribute to contain a string:

```
await page.waitForXPath('//*[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " test ") and string-length(@value) > 0]')
```

If the element is **not** an [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) field, you can use the following expression to wait for the element to contain text:

```
await page.waitForXPath('//*[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " count ") and string-length(text()) > 0]');
```

Comment: [`waitFor` is deprecated](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/find/main#pagewaitforselectororfunctionortimeout-options-args)

Answer (score -1):

```js
await page.waitFor((name) => {
 return document.querySelector('.top .name')?.textContent == name;
}, {timeout: 60000}, test_client2.name);
```

Comment: `waitFor` is deprecated in favor of `waitForFunction`.

Answer (score -1):

`waitForXPath` is simple and works well for finding an element with specific text.

```js
const el = await page.waitForXPath('//*[contains(text(), "Text to check")]');
```