# How do you click on an element with text in Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, html, puppeteer

Is there any method or solution to click on an element with text? I couldn't find one in the API.

For example I have the following HTML:

```html
<div class="elements">
    <button>Button text</button>
    <a href=#>Href text</a>
    <div>Div text</div>
</div>
```

And I want to click on an element in which text is wrapped (click on the button inside `.elements`), like so:

```js
Page.click('Button text', '.elements')
```

Comment: Shared the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47829000/6161265

Comment: If it helps, the page I wanted to perform a click on has jQuery loaded so I was able to & used the evaluate method to execute the jQuery code.

Comment: I hate to post a "look at my answer first" comment, but the top few heavily-upvoted answers are outdated as of Puppeteer >= 18.0.0. [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64626061/6243352) shows simpler approaches than XPath.

Answer (score 184, accepted):

### Short answer

This XPath expression will query a button which contains the text "Button text":

```js
const [button] = await page.$x("//button[contains(., 'Button text')]");
if (button) {
    await button.click();
}
```

To also respect the `<div class="elements">` surrounding the buttons, use the following code:

```js
const [button] = await page.$x("//div[@class='elements']/button[contains(., 'Button text')]");
```

### Explanation

To explain why using the text node (`text()`) is wrong in some cases, let's look at an example:

```html
<div>
    <button>Start End</button>
    <button>Start <em>Middle</em> End</button>
</div>
```

First, let's check the results when using `contains(text(), 'Text')`:

- `//button[contains(text(), 'Start')]` will return both **two** nodes (as expected)
- `//button[contains(text(), 'End')]` will only return **one** nodes (the first) as `text()` returns a list with two texts (`Start`  and  `End`), but `contains` will only check the first one
- `//button[contains(text(), 'Middle')]`  will return **no** results as `text()` does not include the text of child nodes

Here are the XPath expressions for `contains(., 'Text')`, which works on the element itself including its child nodes:

- `//button[contains(., 'Start')]` will return both **two** buttons
- `//button[contains(., 'End')]` will again return both **two** buttons
- `//button[contains(., 'Middle')]`  will return **one** (the last button)

So in most cases, it makes more sense to use the `.` instead of `text()` in an XPath expression.

Comment: something that works with every type of element? i cannot know if the text is inside a button, a p, a div, a span etc.

Comment: @AndreaBisello You can use `//*[...]` instead.

Comment: Could this work if 'Button Text' is in an array?

Comment: Seems like this doesn't work: `The string '//button[contains(., "Message")]' is not a valid XPath expression.`

Answer (score 109):

You may use a XPath selector with [page.$x(expression)](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.1.1/docs/api.md#pagexexpression):

```
const linkHandlers = await page.$x("//a[contains(text(), 'Some text')]");

if (linkHandlers.length > 0) {
  await linkHandlers[0].click();
} else {
  throw new Error("Link not found");
}
```

Check out `clickByText` in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/tokland/d3bae3b6d3c1576d8700405829bbdb52) for a complete example. It takes care of escaping quotes, which is a bit tricky with XPath expressions.

Comment: Awesome - I tried to do it for other tags, but can't make it work. (li, h1,...)
How would you do that?

Comment: @RuneJeppesen Replace `//a[contains` with `//*[contains` to select any element, not just an anchor (`a`) element.

Answer (score 34):

You can also use [`page.evaluate()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) to click elements obtained from [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) that have been filtered by text content:

```js
await page.evaluate(() => {
  [...document.querySelectorAll('.elements button')].find(element => element.textContent === 'Button text').click();
});
```

Alternatively, you can use [`page.evaluate()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) to click an element based on its text content using [`document.evaluate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate) and a corresponding XPath expression:

```js
await page.evaluate(() => {
  const xpath = '//*[@class="elements"]//button[contains(text(), "Button text")]';
  const result = document.evaluate(xpath, document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);

  result.iterateNext().click();
});
```

Answer (score 19):

made quick solution to be able to use advanced css selectors like ":contains(text)"

so using this [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-select) you can just

```
const select = require ('puppeteer-select');

const element = await select(page).getElement('button:contains(Button text)');
await element.click()
```

Comment: Getting `Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: Sizzle is not defined` when tried to use this `const el = await select(page).getElement('[data-testid="ContextualLayerRoot"] [role="menuitem"] div:contains("Instagram Feed")');`
The issue is still open on the github

Comment: Injecting jQuery into the target site is a [one-liner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46987959/6243352), so adding another dependency just to do that seems a bit excessive. Or just use a newer [native Puppeteer text selector](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64626061/6243352), if you don't really need jQuery in general and just need to select an element by text. If you're on an older Puppeteer version, looping over elements manually seems fine for most cases too.

Answer (score 13):

Puppeteer 19.7.1 added ["p" (pseudo) selectors](https://pptr.dev/guides/query-selectors#p-selectors), so `text/` is deprecated in favor of `::-p-text`, which selects on a substring. For example:

```js
const el = await page.waitForSelector("::-p-text(Button text)");
```

Pseudoselectors can work in conjunction with CSS selectors, like

```js
const el = await page.$(".elements button::-p-text(Button text)");
```

---

In Puppeteer >= 18.0.0, selectors have a [`text/`](https://pptr.dev/guides/query-selectors-legacy/#text-selectors-text) prefix that selects on a substring of element text:

```js
const el = await page.waitForSelector("text/Button text");
```

---

With regards to XPath specifically, most relevant to pre-18.0.0 Puppeteer:

Since OP's use case appears to be an exact match on the target string `"Button text"`, `<button>Button text</button>`, `text()` seems like the correct method rather than the less-precise `contains()`.

Although [Thomas makes a good argument](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55424335/6243352) for `contains` when there are sub-elements, avoiding false negatives, using `text()` avoids a false positive when the button is, say, `<button>Button text and more stuff</button>`, which seems just as likely a scenario. It's useful to have both tools on hand so you can pick the more appropriate one on a case-by-case basis.

```js
const xp = '//*[@class="elements"]//button[text()="Button text"]';
const [el] = await page.$x(xp);
await el?.click();
```

Note that many other answers missed the `.elements` parent class requirement.

Another XPath function is [`[normalize-space()="Button text"]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/normalize-space) which "strips leading and trailing white-space from a string, replaces sequences of whitespace characters by a single space" and may be useful for certain cases.

Also, it's often handy to use [`waitForXPath`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagewaitforxpathxpath-options) which waits for, then returns, the element matching the XPath or throws if it's not found within the specified timeout:

```js
const xp = '//*[@class="elements"]//button[text()="Button text"]';
const el = await page.waitForXPath(xp);
await el.click();
```

---

Another flexible approach that works in all environments is to use browser JS to `.find()` or `.filter()` out the element(s) you want by text:

```js
// untrusted click (ignores visibility, sometimes useful):
await page.$$eval(".elements *", els =>
  els
    .find(el => el.textContent.trim().toLowerCase() === "button text")
    .click()
);

// trusted click:
const el = await page.evaluateHandle(() =>
  [...document.querySelectorAll(".elements *")]
    .find(el => el.textContent.trim().toLowerCase() === "button text")
);
await el.click();
```

or:

```js
// untrusted clicks
const els = await page.$$eval(".elements *", els =>
  els
    .filter(el => el.textContent.trim().toLowerCase() === "button text")
    .forEach(el => el.click())
);

// trusted clicks (not ideal)
const els = await page.evaluateHandle(`
  [...document.querySelectorAll(".elements *")]
    .filter(el => el.textContent.trim().toLowerCase() === "button text")
`);
const length = await els.evaluate(els => els.length);

for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  const el = await els.evaluateHandle((els, i) => els[i], i);
  await el.click();
}
```

If you need to wait for this text, you can use `waitForFunction`:

```js
const el = await page.waitForFunction(`
  [...document.querySelectorAll(".elements *")]
    .find(el => el.textContent.trim().toLowerCase() === "button text")
`);
await el.click();
```

---

If you're manipulating a page that happens to have jQuery (or if you [import it yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46987959/6243352)), you can use the `:contains` sizzle pseudoselector syntax:

```js
const el = await page.evaluateHandle(`
  $('.elements :contains("Button text")').first()
`);
```

Answer (score 7):

The solution is

```
(await page.$$eval(selector, a => a
            .filter(a => a.textContent === 'target text')
))[0].click()
```

Comment: Consider replacing `filter(...)[0]` with `find(...)`.

Answer (score 5):

Here is my solution:

```
let selector = 'a';
    await page.$$eval(selector, anchors => {
        anchors.map(anchor => {
            if(anchor.textContent == 'target text') {
                anchor.click();
                return
            }
        })
    });
```

Comment: I'd use `find` or a `for .. of` loop rather than `map` here. `map` in this case allocates, then discards, an array of `undefined` for all `anchors`. Also, the `return` is miseading: `map` will keep going even after it finds the target. Only use `map` if you're going to do something with the return value.

Answer (score 1):

There is no supported css selector syntax for text selector or a combinator option, my work around for this would be:

```
await page.$$eval('selector', selectorMatched => {
    for(i in selectorMatched)
      if(selectorMatched[i].textContent === 'text string'){
          selectorMatched[i].click();
          break;//Remove this line (break statement) if you want to click on all matched elements otherwise the first element only is clicked  
        }
    });
```

Comment: `for(i in selectorMatched)` should be `for (const i in selectorMatched)` to avoid creating a global variable. Also, avoid [`for .. in` to loop arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-for-array-iteration-a-bad-idea). That syntax is intended for objects. Instead, prefer `for (const element of [...selectorMatched])`.

Comment: @ggorlen Actually it'd be `for (const element of selectorMatched) {}`, no need for the spread. Better yet, change `selectorMatched` to `elements` and use `elements.find(e => e.textContent === 'text string')?.click()`, a more functional style.

Answer (score 1):

With puppeteer 12.0.1, the following works for me:

```
await page.click("input[value='Opt1']"); //where value is an attribute of the element input
await page.waitForTimeout(1000);

await page.click("li[value='Nested choice 1']"); //where value is an attribute of the element li after clicking the previous option
await page.waitForTimeout(5000);
```

Answer (score -3):

You can just use the query selector.

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
    document.querySelector('input[type=button]').click();
});
```

Edits ----

You can give your button a className and use that to select the button element since you know exactly what you're trying to click:

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
    document.querySelector('.button]').click();
});
```