# How to click on a link that has a certain content in puppeteer?

Tags: css-selectors, browser-automation, puppeteer

If I have some content in my page such as:

```
<a>Hi!</a>
```

How can I use Google's Puppeteer to automate the clicking of that element?

I need to be able to select it based on its contents alone, not id, class or attribute.

Is there something like `$('a:contains("Hi!")')` that I can leverage to select this element?

How can I do this with https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer

thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to click on element with text in Puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47407791/how-to-click-on-element-with-text-in-puppeteer)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, we have to find element by text.

```js
/**
 * findElemByText - Find an Element By Text
 *
 * @param  {String} str                case-insensitive string to search
 * @param  {String} selector = '*'     selector to search
 * @param  {String} leaf = 'outerHTML' leaf of the element
 * @return {Array}                     array of elements
 */
function findElemByText({str, selector = '*', leaf = 'outerHTML'}){
  // generate regex from string
  const regex = new RegExp(str, 'gmi');

  // search the element for specific word
  const matchOuterHTML = e => (regex.test(e[leaf]))

  // array of elements
  const elementArray = [...document.querySelectorAll(selector)];

  // return filtered element list
  return elementArray.filter(matchOuterHTML)
}

// usage
// findElemByText({str: 'Example', leaf: 'innerHTML', selector: 'title'});
// findElemByText({str: 'Example', selector: 'h1'});
// findElemByText({str: 'Example'});
```

Save it in same folder as your puppeteer script, name it `script.js`.

Now, we can use this in our puppeteer script. We can use ElementHandle, but for simplicity of understanding, I'll use `.evaluate()` function provided with puppeteer.

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://example.com');

  // expose the function
  await page.addScriptTag({path: 'script.js'});

  // Find Element by Text and Click it
  await page.evaluate(() => {
   // click the first element 
   return findElemByText({str: 'More'})[0].click();
  });

  // Wait for navigation, Take Screenshot, Do other stuff
  await page.screenshot({path: 'screenshot.png'});
  await browser.close();
})();
```

Do not copy paste the code above, try to understand it and type them yourself. If the code above fails, try to find why it's failing.

Comment: Thanks :) I remember doing the same with selenium when I needed something "special". Would be nice to have this out of the box with Puppeteer. I guess would be nice to add jquery/css selector on the page and then use the `ElementHandle` to get all those features in one go.

Comment: Excellent answer to the question. I'd add that if possible, it's probably a better idea to add test-ids to the elements you're trying to match, as described here: https://ropig.com/blog/end-end-tests-dont-suck-puppeteer/. This ensures your tests don't break as soon as you update the text on the button/link.

Comment: It looks like the function returns an array starting at the outermost element to the innermost one, i.e. [body, div, p].  Does that sound about right?

Answer (score 21):

### Alternative approach using XPath

There is a much easier way to do it using an [XPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath) expression:

```js
const aElementsWithHi = await page.$x("//a[contains(., 'Hi!')]");
await aElementsWithHi[0].click();
```

Using [`page.$x`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagexexpression), this code finds all `a` elements with the text `Hi!` inside. The result will be an array containing the matching `a` element handles. Using the [`elementHandle.click`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#elementhandleclickoptions) function, we can then click on the element.

Comment: better because you can use waitfor with this

Comment: the answer is more useful than the accepted answer. :D

Comment: Use `page.$x('//a[text()="Hi!"]')` if you want an exact match which seems like a more typical case.