# Selecting a Div inside a Nav

Tags: javascript, selector, puppeteer

I am attempting to automate some functions within Chrome using Puppeteer and Chromium. I'm able to log in, select the main navigation element and the sub-navigation menu appears.  I'm currently playing in the console to find the correct selector to pass into Puppeteer, however, I'm having difficulty.

HTML below:

```
<div id="popupTaskMenu" class="launcher...">
  <div -not important to task></div>
  <nav class="task_launcher_item_heading">
    <div task-item="0" class="task_launcher_item_click">Text</div>
    <div task-item="1" class="task_launcher_item">Text</div>
  </nav>
<div>
```

With in the Chrome console I can get somewhat close to making the `<nav>` items accessible by using `document.getElementsByClassName("task_launcher_item_heading")[0].childNodes[0].innerText`, which will return the innerText of the element, but using the `.click()` method comes back undefined.

Any ideas will surely help.

Comment: Hi, can you show us your click functionality? Where exactly are you using the `.click()` function on

Comment: You might want to use a [more complex selector](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55956674/5627599) and then use `document.querySelector` or `page.$` in puppeteer.

Comment: the more complex selector is a great tool and I am able to send .click() to that element within the JS Console, however, I'm not sure how to use that within puppeteer.  `await page.$('#popupTaskMenu > nav > div.nth-child(2)')` is correct I believe, but how do I send .click() to that?  I'll read and play around some more.

Comment: so I've tried a few different options, and no matter which, I get an error that states "ERR Evaluation failed: DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#popupTaskMenu > nav > div.nth-child(2)' is not a valid selector.  Last line I tried was `await page.evaluate((selector) => document.querySelector('#popupTaskMenu > nav > div.nth-child(2)').click();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, someday I'm going to be a smart person...  my problem was I was using `#popupTaskMenu > nav > div.nth-child(2)`  when it should have been `#popupTaskMenu > nav > div:nth-child(2)`

I should have used a COLON rather than the period!!!!  2 hours of my life people!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are just trying to target this guy and make him do something.

```
 <div task-item="0" class="task_launcher_item_click">Text</div>
```

if that is the case, can you use `const Nav = document.getElementById(); 
 await Nav.click();` function instead and give it it's own ID while still retaining the `task_launcher_item_click` class?

Once you have the click on that specific element can you use a promise function https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#frameclickselector-options

```
const [response] = await Promise.all([
  page.waitForNavigation(waitOptions),
  frame.click(selector, clickOptions),
]);
```

or an attribute selector https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#attribute-selectors

```
const element = await page.$('[href="http://www.iana.org/domains/example"]');
    await element.click();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```