# How can I get an element by xpath?

Tags: puppeteer

I need to find any element in DOM by xpath. I already tried the following:

```
let el = await page.$x('//*[@id="readium-right-panel"]/ul/li[1]');
```

The returning error is:

> TypeError: page.$x is not a function

Answer (score 5):

Looks like your puppeteer version may be outdated

```
page.$x()
```

is new to 1.0.0

Answer (score 3):

the problem most probably might be because of the older puppeteer version. You might want to check the puppeteer version in your package.json file.

SMALL NOTE: `npm i https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/` does not upgrade puppeteer.

if(puppeteer version >1.0.0)

### ###try this,###

suppose that //*[@id="ng-app"] is the global prefix then u add it before the Xpath variable. I have used interpolation for this.

```
    await page.waitForXPath(`//*[@id="ng-app"]/${Xpath}`, { visible: true });//waiting for the xPath element to be visible
    const elementToClick = await page.$x(`//*[@id="ng-app"]/${Xpath}`);
await elementToClick[0].click();
```

### this is an example to click the element extracted of course.

in your case it will be

```
    await page.waitForXPath('//*[@id="readium-right-panel"]/ul/li[1]');
    let el =await page.$x(`//*[@id="readium-right-panel"]/ul/li[1]`);
await el[0].click();
```

source:[the API DOCS Of Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v3.1.0/docs/api.md#pagexexpression)

Answer (score 2):

Although this question was asked back in 2018 when `page.waitForXPath` was introduced, it's relevant again in 2024 onward because `page.$x` and `page.waitForXPath` have been deprecated for some time and were [removed as of v22](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/compare/puppeteer-core-v21.11.0...puppeteer-core-v22.0.0).

Use `waitForSelector` with a [p-xpath](https://pptr.dev/guides/query-selectors#xpath-selectors--p-xpath) for now:

```js
const xp = '::-p-xpath(//*[@id="readium-right-panel"]/ul/li[1])';
const el = await page.waitForSelector(xp);
await el.click();
```

Eventually, the [locators API](https://pptr.dev/guides/locators/) may be less experimental and the recommended approach for auto-waiting and selecting, regardless of whether you're using xpath or some other selection syntax. At the time of writing, Puppeteer locators still seem immature.

As an aside, regardless of what function it's in, [overusing XPath can be an antipattern](https://blog.appsignal.com/2023/06/14/puppeteer-in-nodejs-more-antipatterns-to-avoid.html#using-xpath-instead-of-css-selectors) in Puppeteer. This could be written with CSS more cleanly, both in terms of the CSS syntax itself, but also the avoidance of `::-p-xpath()`.

```js
const sel = "#readium-right-panel > ul > li:first-child";
const el = await page.waitForSelector(sel);
await el.click();
```

But even this is not ideal, since it rigidly specifies a hierarchy and requires a certain index, which can break easily. There's usually a better way to identify that list item, like text contents, a role or a label.

Historically, XPath was also used to select elements by text in Puppeteer, but this is no longer necessary since new syntax has been introduced specifically to select by text. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64626061/6243352) for details. Between CSS, text and aria selectors, the use case for XPath should be very narrow nowadays.

---

For completeness, full example for any Puppeteer version that supports p-selectors:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^22.2.0

const html = `<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>
<div id="readium-right-panel">
  <ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script>
const sel = "#readium-right-panel > ul > li:first-child";
document.querySelector(sel)
  .addEventListener("click", e => {
    e.target.textContent = "clicked";
  });
</script></body></html>`;

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.setContent(html);
  const xp = '::-p-xpath(//*[@id="readium-right-panel"]/ul/li[1])';
  const el = await page.waitForSelector(xp);
  await el.click();
  console.log(await el.evaluate(el => el.textContent)); // => clicked
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

<sub>Disclosure: I'm the author of the linked blog post.</sub>

Answer (score -1):

Following should work

```
let el = await page.xpath('//*[@id="readium-right-panel"]/ul/li[1]');
```