# How to get text from xPath in Puppeteer node js

Tags: puppeteer, jest-puppeteer

[image]

I need to get a text from the span tag and to verify whether the text equals to "check".

How can I achieve this in puppeteer?

Below is the example of the code I've written, if anyone could put me help me figure this out, please.

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    // "slowMo": 50,
    args: ["--start-fullscreen"],
    defaultViewport: null,
  });
  //Page
  const page2 = await browser.newPage();

  await page2.goto("https://www.flipkart.com");
  await page2.waitFor(2000);
  await page2.$x("//input[@class='_2zrpKA _1dBPDZ']").then(async (ele) => {
    await ele[0].type(username);
  });
  await page2.waitFor(2000);
  await page2.$x("//input[@type='password']").then(async (ele) => {
    await ele[0].type(password);
  });
  await page2.waitFor(2000);
  await page2
    .$x("//button[@class='_2AkmmA _1LctnI _7UHT_c']")
    .then(async (ele) => {
      await ele[0].click();
    });
  await page2.waitFor(2000);
  await page2.$x("//input[@class='LM6RPg']").then(async (ele) => {
    await ele[0].type("iPhone 11");
  });
  await page2.waitFor(2000);
  await page2.$x("//button[@class='vh79eN']").then(async (ele) => {
    await ele[0].click();
  });
  await page2.waitFor(2000);
  await page2.$x("//div[@class='col col-7-12']/div").then(async (ele) => {
    await ele[0].click();
  });
  await page2.waitFor(2000);
  let [element] = await page2.$x('//span[@class="_2aK_gu"]');
  let text = await page2.evaluate((element) => element.textContent, element);
  if (text.includes("Check")) {
    console.log("Check Present");
  }
  if (text.includes("Change")) {
    console.log("Change Present");
  }
})();
```

Comment: Can you show us your code ? What have you tried/searched ? When you have text output, [don't take a picture but copy paste the output in your POST](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text) The html can be copied as well with right click -> copy as outerHTML.

Comment: I tried the following:   await this.page.$x('//span[@class="_2aK_gu"]/text()')

Comment: Thanks to post the whole code

Comment: This seems like an [overuse of XPath](https://blog.appsignal.com/2023/06/14/puppeteer-in-nodejs-more-antipatterns-to-avoid.html#using-xpath-instead-of-css-selectors). `[@class='_2zrpKA _1dBPDZ']` is [too precise](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#misusing-developer-tools-generated-selectors)--if another class is added, or the order of the two classes switches, this will fail unnecessarily. The current approach as of Puppeteer 22 is [-p-xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78054219/6243352) syntax in `waitForSelector`, for the rare occasions when you do need to use XPath.

Answer (score 4):

//get the xpath of the webelement

```
const [getXpath] = await page.$x('//div[]');
```

//get the text using innerText from that webelement

```
const getMsg = await page.evaluate(name => name.innerText, getXpath);
```

//Log the message on screen

```
console.log(getMsg)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: `page.evaluate(name => name.innerText, getXpath);` can be written as `getXpath.evaluate(el => el.innerText);` (although `getXpath` isn't the clearest variable name, and I'm not sure why `name` was used to refer to a DOM element).

Answer (score 3):

Here is the complete code for getting div or any html element data using xpath....

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

async function scrape () {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    const page =  await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto("https://twitter.com/elonmusk", {waitUntil: "networkidle2"})
    await page.waitForXPath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/section/div/div/div[1]/div/div/article/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/a/div/div[1]/span/span');

    let [el] = await page.$x('/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/section/div/div/div[1]/div/div/article/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/a/div/div[1]/span/span');

    // console.log()

    const names = await page.evaluate(name => name.innerText, el);
    console.log(names);


    await browser.close();
};

scrape();
```

Comment: `page.waitForXPath` is [removed as of v22](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/releases/tag/puppeteer-core-v22.0.0). You can use the [-p-xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78054219/6243352) syntax in `waitForSelector`.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the text form the selected element like this:

```js
await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "networkidle2"});
await page.waitForXPath('//span[@class="_2aK_gu"]');
//assuming it's the first element
let [element] = await page.$x('//span[@class="_2aK_gu"]');
let text = await page.evaluate(element => element.textContent, element);
```

Note that `page.$x` returns an array of ElementHandles, so the code here assumes it's the first element. I'd suggest you chose a more specific XPath than a class as many elements may have it.

---

For the condition:

```js
if (text.includes("Check"))
    //do this
else if (text.includes("Change"))
    //do that
```

Comment: I'm not using jest-puppeteer ! So could you please provide me a solution to get text  without using jest puppeteer ?

Comment: @RajeshG edited the answer, let me know if it's not clear.

Comment: Agreed ! Tried this earlier and I received the following error in my console...'Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of undefined
           at __puppeteer_evaluation_script__:2:34'

Comment: @RajeshG probably the classname is a random string that changes so it can't find the element. can you provide more details on top of that snapshot? like page's url or html

Comment: URL:- https://www.flipkart.com/apple-iphone-11-black-128-gb/p/itm06bac28995200?pid=MOBFKCTSYAPWYFJ5&lid=LSTMOBFKCTSYAPWYFJ580EM6T&marketplace=FLIPKART&srno=s_1_1&otracker=search&otracker1=search&fm=SEARCH&iid=c6b61ecd-a5d6-411b-baa8-3ad6b15c9ad0.MOBFKCTSYAPWYFJ5.SEARCH&ppt=sp&ppn=sp&ssid=gsr9ittk6o0000001578892687146&qH=f6cdfdaa9f3c23f3  <span class="_2aK_gu">Change<div class="_11cw91 _2jiIfZ _1VbEkR  _3HQXAr E753YP _3fm5As _1SD9nm S3vLVv"><div class="_2h52bo _15sV4W _3sqwCr">Check pincode<button class="_2AkmmA DoInvC">✕</button></div></div></span>

Comment: Req:- If that particular span class contains 'Change' - then do some operation, else if contains 'Check' - then do some operation

Comment: @RajeshG ran the code on the website and it worked fine. are you sure you're also waiting for the xpath using `await page.waitForXPath()`?

Comment: Yes..If I use wait for xpath it is throwing Timeout error

Comment: @RajeshG it's just a simple if else, see my edited answer

Comment: @RajeshG I cannot reproduce the issue you're having as it's working fine on my side. set the `headless` to false see if the website is loading correctly, then inspect the element check if you can get the element using `$x('//span[@class="_2aK_gu"]')` in console.

Comment: Headless is set to false... And defaultview port is also set to null.

Comment: @RajeshG did you check the element? were you able to get it with `$x()` I put?

Comment: Yes I'm able to get the element !

Comment: @RajeshG then there is something going on with your code, edit your answer and post your code so I can take a look

Comment: @RajeshG I checked the relevant part and it works fine on my side on the url you provided. This is my suggestion: comment out the code up to the last part and run the code. if it works correctly, as it should, it means the issue is most probably in the previous parts (clicking/authentication) that doesn't lead to the correct page

Comment: Yeah ... Since the clicking upon the product , it opens in the new tab, it looks like the page is not getting retained. Any solution for this ?

Comment: @RajeshG if the click opens a new tab it's a different problem. the reason it doesn't find the element is it looks for the element in the wrong tab/page. you need to look for the element in the opened tab. create a new question and I'll post an answer there since it's irrelevant to the topic here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59712283/puppeteer-finds-the-element-in-the-wrong-tab