# TypeError: page.waitForXPath is not a function (Puppeteer/Puppeteer-extra)

Tags: javascript, node.js, xpath, puppeteer

Since i changed the cpu, ram, motherboard, and psu of my pc (and also reset my windows), the waitForXPath function stopped working for no reason. (and i really need it, since its like one of the most important things)

---

I tried: Reinstalling nodejs, visual studio code, asking chagpt and github copilot ofcourse, researching on the internet, reinstalling node modules and updating everything to the latest version.
I Expected: The code simply waiting and clicking a button.
The code:

```
await page.waitForXPath('//*[@id="loginContainer"]/div/div/div[3]'); 
const FClick = await page.$x('//*[@id="loginContainer"]/div/div/div[3]');
await FClick[0].click('//*[@id="loginContainer"]/div/div/div[3]')
```

Full Error:

```
await page.waitForXPath('//*[@id="loginContainer"]/div/div/div[3]');
                   ^

TypeError: page.waitForXPath is not a function
    at C:\Users\user\Desktop\Shortify\index.js:172:20
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Node.js v20.11.1
```

Comment: You might have upgraded your Puppeteer version, or your package.json is a wildcard (it'd be good to show it). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78054219/6243352). `waitForXPath` has been deprecated and was removed as of Puppeteer v22. Use `const el = await page.waitForSelector('::-p-xpath(//*[@id="loginContainer"]/div/div/div[3])');`.

Comment: or you can join the rest of us and use css: `page.waitForSelector('#loginContainer > div > div > div:nth-child(3)')`