# Wait using Path (Puppeteer)

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, xpath, puppeteer

I'm using Puppeteer 22.6.0 with NodeJS for web scraping, I'm trying to pause the script until a specific `h1` element is visible, the issue is there are multiple `h1` elements on the page and the only possible way to identify that certain `h1` is with checking if it says a certain message, like: `<h1>something</h1>`

Since I can't do this using a selector *(as far as I know)*, I tried using `page.waitForXPath()` but I get the error:

```js
TypeError: page.waitForXPath is not a function
```

I have searched for a solution but it seems the method has been removed, is there any workaround for this? Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get an element by xpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48165646/how-can-i-get-an-element-by-xpath)

Comment: Use [`waitForSelector`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78054219/6243352) `page.waitForSelector("::-p-xpath(//h1[text()='something'])")`, but as the linked post mentions, you [probably don't need XPath](https://blog.appsignal.com/2023/06/14/puppeteer-in-nodejs-more-antipatterns-to-avoid.html#using-xpath-instead-of-css-selectors) in the first place: `page.waitForSelector("h1::-p-text('something')")` is much cleaner.