# Use puppeteer to search for element based on inner text

Tags: node.js, chromium, puppeteer, innertext

I've been attempting to do some web scraping using puppeteer, and I've run into the following problem: [image] I want to click an element that has a specific inner text (in this case 'INHERITANCE TAX RETURN'), but everything else about the element seems to be identical to a lot of other elements on the page. I was wondering if anyone knew a way to search for an element based on its inner text. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47407791/puppeteer-click-on-element-with-text

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Puppeteer: Click on element with text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47407791/puppeteer-click-on-element-with-text)

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried:

```
const linkHandlers = await page.$x("//span[contains(text(), 'INHERITANCE TAX RETURN')]");
if (linkHandlers.length > 0) {
  await linkHandlers[0].click();
} else {
  throw new Error("Link not found");
}
```