# Press the submit button using page.waitForSelector and page.click

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, puppeteer

I want to press the submit button that looks like this

```html
<input type="submit" name="ok" value="example" class="ibro_schalter_03">
```

I would use `'[name=ok]'` but there are other buttons next to each other that also have the same name.

When i tried to use `'[value=example]'` I got an error

> Error: Evaluation failed: DOMException:
> Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document':
> '[value=example]' is not a valid selector.

Can i get some help with it?

Comment: Is `example` the actual value? If you have "schalter-eins" then you need to escape or quote the dash - In the browser you can use CSS.escape(value) but that might not be available to node [more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52251592/puppeteer-escape-square-brackets-in-selector)

Answer (score 1):

Change `'[value=example]'` to `'[value="example"]`

Answer (score 0):

Converting my comment to answer

Is `example` the actual value? If you have "schalter-eins" then you need to quote the value: `'[value="schalter-eins"]'`

Alternatively escape the value - In the browser you can use CSS.escape(value) but that might not be available to node [more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52251592/puppeteer-escape-square-brackets-in-selector)