# Click on outer element with inner element with specific text in Puppeteer

Tags: node.js, xpath, puppeteer

How can I click on an outer element that contains a `span` with specific text via puppeteer?

For example I have the following HTML code:

```
<div role="button">
  <div>
    <span>
      <span>OK</span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I would like to click on the most outer element (role = button). In order to click on the span with the Ok text I would do the next thing:

```
const [button] = await page.$x("//span[contains(., 'Ok')]");
if (button) {
    await button.click();
}
```

But how can I click on the outer element using this text identifier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`descendant`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/descendant) expression to query for child elements. Quote from the link:

> The `descendant` axis indicates all of the children of the context node, and all of their children, and so forth.

Your XPath expression then looks like this:

```xml
//div[@role='button' and descendant::span[contains(., 'Ok')]]
```

Depending on your use case you might also want to check out [this information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55424335/5627599) about the difference of `contains(text(), ...)` and `contains(., ...)`.