# Puppeteer - how to click a link with certain text

Tags: puppeteer

I want to click a link with certain text using Puppeteer.

```
<a class="text-major ev-pick-this-event" 
    href="/cgi-bin/ncommerce3/SEGetEventInfo?ticketCode=GS%3AAMTX%3AHUSKERS%3ASLP2%3A&amp;linkID=BQFN80-AMTX&amp;shopperContext=&amp;pc=&amp;caller=&amp;appCode=&amp;groupCode=SLP&amp;cgc=&amp;dataAccId=129&amp;locale=en_US&amp;siteId=ev_BQFN80-AMTX">
    HUSKERS - SLP2 - Ranges
</a>
```

Comment: try this one https://browsee.io/blog/puppeteer-how-to-find-a-link-element-with-a-certain-text/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47407791/puppeteer-click-on-element-with-text

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Puppeteer: Click on element with text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47407791/puppeteer-click-on-element-with-text)

Answer (score 2):

It can be done with [XPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions)'s [`contains()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/contains) and [`text()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#node-tests) methods, for example:

```js
const [link] = await page.$x('//a[contains(text(), "certain text")]') // returns an array, as the first element will be used it can be destructured
await link.click()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    let click = await page.evaluate(() => {
      try {
        const getText = e => (e ? e.innerText.trim() : '')
        let links = document.querySelectorAll('nav a')
        for (let i = 0, n = links.length; i < n; i++) {
          if (getText(links[i]) === 'Home') {
            links[i].click()
            return getText(links[i])
          }
        }
      } catch (e) {
        return e.toString()
      }
    })
    console.log({ click })
```

Comment: Please improve this CodeOnly-Answer by adding an Explanation what it does and why it helps the OP.