# Puppeteer - Check if specific text exists

Tags: javascript, xpath, text, puppeteer, contains

I'm using puppeteer to check for a specific text that appears on the webpage. My code to check is as follows:

```
if ((await page.waitForXPath('//span[contains(text(), "Subscription Confirmed")]',30000)) !== null) {
  chk = await page.evaluate(el => el.innerText, await page.$x('//span[contains(text(), "Subscription Confirmed")]'))
  chk = 'Success'
} else {
  // do something else
  chk = 'Failed'
}
```

This doesn't seem to detect the text for some reason. I have attached a screenshot of the DOM of the webpage where you can see the text - [DOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLBDK.jpg). Hoping someone could help.

Comment: On your screenshot, the text is contained in `h2` element, not in `span`.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me in a jest test:

```js
  await page.waitForXPath('//*[contains(text(), "SOME TEXT")]')
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
if ((await page.waitForXPath('//*[contains(text(), "Subscription Confirmed")]',30000)) !== null) {
   chk = await page.evaluate(el => el.innerText, await page.$x('//*[contains(text(), "Subscription Confirmed")]'))
   chk = 'Success'
} else { 
   chk = 'Failed'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have simply confused `span` and `h1` in your selector. However, I'd like to offer a few suggestions and notes to improve upon other answers.

- Always use booleans like true and false rather than strings `"Success"` and `"Failed"`.
- `waitForXPath` throws when the timeout expires, so the `if` is unnecessary.
- The second argument to `waitForXPath` should be `{timeout: 30000}` rather than `30000`.
- Unless you override it elsewhere in your code, 30 seconds is the default timeout so you can omit that option.
- Scope variables with `let` or `const`.
- [Use the return value of `waitFor_`](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#not-using-the-return-value-of-waitforselector-and-waitforxpath) rather than re-selecting the element.
- `waitForXPath` is deprecated in favor of `waitForSelector("::-p-xpath(...)")`.

Putting these suggestions together, we have:

```js
const xp = '::-p-xpath(//h1[contains(text(), "Subscription Confirmed")])';
const el = await page.waitForSelector(xp);
const text = await el.evaluate(el => el.textContent);
```

You can wrap this in a `try`/`catch` if you expect failure, or use the shorthand:

```js
const xp = '::-p-xpath(//h1[contains(text(), "Subscription Confirmed")])';
const el = await page.waitForSelector(xp).catch(() => null);

if (el) {
  const text = await el.evaluate(el => el.textContent);
}
```

But we can improve this. Puppeteer now has the `::-p-text()` pseudoselector which is a bit more succinct:

```js
const el = await page.waitForSelector("h1::-p-text(Subscription Confirmed)");
const text = await el.evaluate(el => el.textContent);
```

Now, since you're selecting by full text and not using a substring, you basically already know the text, so there's no point in getting it!

If you want to check whether specific text exists or not and you don't want to wait for it to appear, you can use:

```js
const exists = await page.$("h1::-p-text(Subscription Confirmed)");

if (exists) {
  // it exists
}
```

`exists` will be null if not found or the ElementHandle otherwise. This seems closer to your original intent.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47407791/how-do-you-click-on-an-element-with-text-in-puppeteer/64626061#64626061) for a canonical resource to selecting by text in Puppeteer.