# Puppeteer: how to focus on element with XPath

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I use the Puppeteer framework to automize tests.
I need to find an element as per a text:

```
await page.focus(//span[contains(text(), 'Name')]])

<span class="some_placeholder">Name</span>
<span class="some_placeholder">Phone Number</span>
```

But in this case the following error occurs:

```
Evaluation failed: DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on Document '' is not a valid selector..
```

`span[class='name']` finds some elements successfully but only one element is needed.

`focus()` accepts a CSS selector and does not accept `contains()` or `text()` methods.

How should I code the search condition correctly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to click on element with text in Puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47407791/how-to-click-on-element-with-text-in-puppeteer). It's virtually the same as far as the selection process goes if you allow for calling the similar method `.click()` rather than `.focus()`, and the dupe suggestion is the canonical thread for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You caan use XPath with [`page.$x()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagexexpression) and then call [`elementHandle.focus()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#elementhandlefocus):

```js
const [element] = await page.$x('//span[contains(text(), "Name")]');
await element.focus();
```