# How to click on text in Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, html, css, automation, puppeteer

Is there any method (didn't find in API) or solution to click on element with text?

For example I have HTML:

```
<div class="_5THWM1">flex
<span class="_2i7N3j">Sort By</ span>
<div class="_10UF8M 3LsR0e>Relevance</div>
<div class="_10UF8M">Popularity</div>
<div class-"_10UF8M'>Price -- Low to High</div>
<div class="_10UF8M>Price -- High to Low</div>
<div class="_10UF8M" >Newest First</div>
</div>
```

I want to click on Price -- Low to high but with the same classes I don't know how to click and I don't know how to click on text. Can anyone help me with this, please?

I am using Puppeteer and please write code to this.

Comment: How to click an element is [clearly documented](//github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#elementhandleclickoptions). Is the problem _finding_ the element?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to click on element with text in Puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47407791/how-to-click-on-element-with-text-in-puppeteer)

Answer (score 0):

Not really but you can use xpath or you can use find:

```
page.$$eval('div', divs => divs.find(div => div.innerText.match(/some text')).click())
```