# How to get the selector after filtering from selectorAll?

Tags: javascript, html, puppeteer

I want to get selector from nodelist for specific filtering to pass to puppeteer waitForSelector that need css selector. i expect cause apple is 2nd child. i expect get `button:nth-child(2)`

```js
const fruits = document.querySelectorAll('button');

for (const fruit of fruits) {
  if (fruit.textContent == 'Apple') {
    // get the element handle and pass to waitForSelector
    console.log('Apple')
  }
}
```

```html
<button type="button">Orange</button>
<button type="button">Apple</button>
```

Comment: So you are attempting to determine the index of the child? You'd need to keep an counter as you're iterating through `fruits`.

Comment: Have you made any attempts at writing a solution yourself? What went wrong with your attempt(s), in what way? Do you have any code you could share to show your attempts?

Comment: Would it be easier to add data attributes to each button and then create a bespoke selector based on them: `const apple = 'button[data-type="apple"]';`, for example?

Comment: @Andy ow, i see. thats clever ways. use setAttribute inside evaluate. thx bro

Comment: Is this inside an `evaluateHandle`? If so, simply `return fruit` and you should be good to go. `page.evaluateHandle(() => [...document.querySelectorAll("button")].find(e => e.textContent.trim() === "Apple"))` is shorter, and xpath is also possible, see [How to click on element with text in Puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47407791/how-to-click-on-element-with-text-in-puppeteer/64626061#64626061).

Comment: @ggorlen return fruit is not something that waitForSelector need. fruit return HTMLCollection. i solve already with andy suggest.

Comment: There isn't any `data-type` in your HTML though so I don't see how that would work. Yeah, if you're waiting for an element with text content, replace the above function with `waitForFunction`. I guess I'm not really clear what the use case or goal is here, though.

Comment: @ggorlen nice suggest to use waitForFunction for this situation. i keep think why i need waitforselector. if i manipulate element of document that already available.

Answer (score 0):

As suggest from andy, i solved it this ways. credit to andy

```js
const fruits = document.querySelectorAll('button');

for (const fruit of fruits) {
  if (fruit.textContent == 'Apple') {
    fruit.setAttribute('data-type', 'Apple');
    break
  }
}

return document.querySelector('button[data-type=Apple]')
```

```html
<button type="button">Orange</button>
<button type="button">Apple</button>
```

Comment: Messing with the host page's `data-` attributes seems hacky and unnecessary. There's [almost certainly a better way](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676) if you don't mind providing more context.