# How do I dispatch a Puppeteer '.on' event?

Tags: puppeteer

Example, if I don't dispatch it, this event throws an error when I close the browser.

```js
await page.on("response", async resp => {
  if (resp.url().includes("navigator.successRedirect")) {
    let code = await page.$eval("pre", el => el.textContent);
    code = JSON.parse(code).authorizationCode;
    console.log(code);
    // page.off('response', this) - Here I want to dispatch this event, how can I do that?
    await browser.close();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you store the function in a variable, you can use `off`:

```js
const handleResponse = async response => {
  if (response.url().includes("navigator.successRedirect")) {
    let code = await page.$eval("pre", el => el.textContent);
    code = JSON.parse(code).authorizationCode;
    console.log(code);
    page.off("response", handleResponse);
    await browser.close();
  }
};
page.on("response", handleResponse);
```

However, this may be an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/399876) because `waitForResponse` can do this without having to manually register a listener, allowing you to avoid the callback and stay in the promise chain:

```js
await page.waitForResponse(response =>
  response.url().includes("navigator.successRedirect")
);
let code = await page.$eval("pre", el => el.textContent);
code = JSON.parse(code).authorizationCode;
console.log(code);
await browser.close();
```

Depending on the site, you could also [wait for the `<pre>` element's text to change](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74917172/6243352) or to [be nonempty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46825300/wait-for-text-to-appear-when-using-puppeteer), or pull the data you want out of the response, if that response has the data you want as a payload.

Note that [`await page.on()` is misleading](https://blog.appsignal.com/2023/02/08/puppeteer-in-nodejs-common-mistakes-to-avoid.html#awaiting-synchronous-puppeteer-calls) because `on` doesn't return a promise.