# Why only .find takes into account all elements of .querySelectorAll, and not .forEach?

Tags: javascript, html, puppeteer

I'm building something with puppeteer, and because the DOM tree isn't very intuitive (on purpose I suppose), I have to find elements in a weird way. Here's the code that works:

```
    const props = await propertyPage.evaluate(async () => {
      const elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('*'));

      const price = (() => {
        const element = elements.find(div => div.innerHTML?.trim().startsWith('£'))
        if (!element) return null
        return Number(element.innerHTML.replace(/[^\d.]/g, ""));
      })();
      const propertyType = (() => {
        const element = elements.find(div => div.textContent?.trim() === 'PROPERTY TYPE')
        if (!element) return null
        return element?.parentNode?.children[1]?.children[1]?.children[0]?.innerHTML;
      })();
      const bedrooms = (() => {
        const element = elements.find(div => div.textContent?.trim() === 'BEDROOMS')
        if (!element) return null
        return Number(element?.parentNode?.children[1]?.children[1]?.children[0]?.innerHTML?.replace(/[^\d.]/g, ''))||null;
      })();
      const bathrooms = (() => {
        const element = elements.find(div => div.textContent?.trim() === 'BATHROOMS')
        if (!element) return null
        return Number(element?.parentNode?.children[1]?.children[1]?.children[0]?.innerHTML?.replace(/[^\d.]/g, ''))||null;
      })();
      const tenure = (() => {
        const element = elements.find(div => div.textContent?.trim() === 'TENURE')
        if (!element) return null
        return element?.parentNode?.children[1]?.children[1]?.children[0]?.innerHTML;
      })();
      const size = (() => {
        const element = elements.find(div => div.textContent?.trim() === 'SIZE')
        if (!element) return null
        return element?.parentNode?.children[1]?.children[1]?.children[0]?.innerHTML;
      })();

      return { price, propertyType, bedrooms, bathrooms, tenure, size };
   })
```

Here's the code that supposed to work, but it doesn't:

```
    const props = await propertyPage.evaluate(async () => {
      const elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('*'));

      let price = null;
      let propertyType = null;
      let bedrooms = null;
      let bathrooms = null;
      let tenure = null;
      let size = null;
      elements.forEach((potentialElement) => {
        price = (() => {
          const element =
            (potentialElement as any).dataset?.testid === 'priceQualifier';
          if (!element) return null;
          return potentialElement?.parentNode?.children[1]?.children[0]
            ?.children[0]?.children[0]?.innerHTML;
        })();
        propertyType = (() => {
          const element =
            potentialElement.textContent?.trim() === 'PROPERTY TYPE';
          if (!element) return null;
          return potentialElement?.parentNode?.children[1]?.children[1]
            ?.children[0]?.innerHTML;
        })();
        bedrooms = (() => {
          const element = potentialElement.textContent?.trim() === 'BEDROOMS';
          if (!element) return null;
          return potentialElement?.parentNode?.children[1]?.children[1]
            ?.children[0]?.innerHTML;
        })();
        bathrooms = (() => {
          const element = potentialElement.textContent?.trim() === 'BATHROOMS';
          if (!element) return null;
          return potentialElement?.parentNode?.children[1]?.children[1]
            ?.children[0]?.innerHTML;
        })();
        tenure = (() => {
          const element = potentialElement.textContent?.trim() === 'TENURE';
          if (!element) return null;
          return potentialElement?.parentNode?.children[1]?.children[1]
            ?.children[0]?.innerHTML;
        })();
        size = (() => {
          const element = potentialElement.textContent?.trim() === 'SIZE';
          if (!element) return null;
          return potentialElement?.parentNode?.children[1]?.children[1]
            ?.children[0]?.innerHTML;
        })();
      });

      return { price, propertyType, bedrooms, bathrooms, tenure, size };
    });
```

In the second case, it seems like `elements` is just the initial elements like header, footer etc.

I tried waiting for a promise with some time in a timeout, but hasn't solved the issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's not exactly clear what your question is, but `.forEach()` is implemented on the node list returned from `.querySelectorAll()` (so you don't need `Array.from()` when you want to use `.forEach()`). But, `.find()` is an `Array` method and so you do need to convert the node list returned from `.querySelectorAll()` into an `Array` if you wish to use that.

Comment: The issue is the arrays differ if used with `.find` vs `.forEach`. I tried `for (const x of elements)` too, but the correct elements only seem to be found with `.find`, and with looping through them, they are very incomplete

Comment: This code is pretty strange on a number of levels. I suggest sharing your actual site--there's surely a much cleaner way to arrange this than a bunch of repetition and hardcoded chains like `element?.parentNode?.children[1]?.children[1]?.children[0]?.`. That's liable to break and very verbose. Grabbing all elements in the tree, then using `.find()` is generally not done. 97% of the time, use `querySelector` and CSS classes and ids to query the DOM. If it seems hard, there's usually a better way, but without the site and expected output, there's no way to provide a better option here.

Comment: Actually, querying by text is not entirely unreasonable, and doing it without XPath does involve looping over multiple elements by hand, but Puppeteer has provided [pretty clean ways of doing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47407791/how-do-you-click-on-an-element-with-text-in-puppeteer/64626061#64626061), and even if you do use the native DOM, you can still do this without repetition. But in your case, you're using not just the text, but also chains of parent/child relationships, so it's not quite so clear. See [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/233676#233676).

Comment: The issue is that `querySelectorAll()` doesn't return an array, it returns a `NodeList`. This is an array-like type, so you can index it with `[]` like an array, but it doesn't implement most array methods. It implements `.forEach()`, but not `.find()` or `.map()`.

Comment: @Barmar the case is the same if I don't convert the `NodeList` into an array, and just looping through the elements with `forEach`

Comment: The first code block uses `find()`, which returns the first element that matches the criteria. The second code block uses `forEach()`, so it overwrites the variables like `price` and `propertyType` each time through the loop, and the final values are from the last element in the array.